# How to change master key of DESfire cards?What is deciphered key?

Tags: smartcard, mifare

I want to change the master key of a *DESfire* card. I read 
[mifare DESFire datasheet](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fneteril.org%2Ffiles%2FM075031_desfire.pdf&ei=ZWc7VZnYN8vtUpvogagB&usg=AFQjCNGXl7Hm7RbpQ33-6LE91nUsR2lExA&bvm=bv.91665533,d.d24) already, but as I am new in this field, I couldn't understand it.

*It is explained how to Change the Key at page `37` of above document.*

Can anybody give me an example or a step by step tutorial for changing keys? (Including associated APDU commands)

What is `deciphered key` that is mentioned in the document? 
Shall I decipher my new key and then use it in the command? If so, how do I decipher key data?

Comment: Just so people are aware .. the document linked to is old information and, while correct in many things, is not correct in all (changing keys is one of the areas that it is incorrect on .. as well as the accepted answer about ALWAYS decrypting vs ALWAYS encrypting)..  I suppose it depends on what generation of DESFire you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `decipheredKey` is CBC-mode decrypted value of the new key with a zero initial vector.

This is a Mifare DESFire feature: terminal **always decrypts** (even to hide plaintext!) and the DESFire card **always encrypts**. It is based on fact, that decryption and encryption using symmetric ciphers like DES, 3DES or AES are inverse functions, which can be both used both for hiding and revealing plaintext.

It helps to improve performance - DESFire card does not have to switch the cipher mode from encryption to decryption with each APDU.

See page 12 of your document.